# Using RestSharp (C#) to make requests to aws

Tags: c#, rest, amazon-s3, restsharp

I am trying to use the REST interface of AWS S3 for a web service which stores and retrieves file pieces in a simmilar way git does (via hash and a directory system based off of it). I am using the RestSharp client library to make these calls, as the AWS SDK is out of the question (the web service is actually required to work with AWS-like stores such as Hitachi HDS) and in general, as more storage platforms would be added, it was felt a standardised method would be best to perform over-the-wire communication.

The problem is that RestSharp may be adding some extra payload, as S3 is crying about having more than one data element to save.

The following code is the core storage logic, and it should be noted I am using Ninject to handle any dependancies.

```
public bool PutBytesInStore(string piecehash, byte[] data)
        {
            string method = "POST";
            string hash;
            using (var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                hash = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1.ComputeHash(data));
            }

            string contentType = "application/octet-stream";
            string date = new DateTime().ToString("{EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}");
            string file = string.Format("pieces/{0}/{1}/{2}", piecehash.Substring(0, 2), piecehash.Substring(0, 6),
                piecehash);

            //Creating signature
            var sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sBuilder.Append(method).Append("\n");
            sBuilder.Append(contentType).Append("\n");
            sBuilder.Append(date).Append("\n");
            sBuilder.Append(hash).Append("\n");
            sBuilder.Append(file).Append("\n");
            var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(new HMACSHA1(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_password)).ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sBuilder.ToString())));

            _request.Method = Method.POST;
            _request.AddFile(piecehash, data, piecehash);
            _request.AddHeader("Date", date);
            _request.AddHeader("Content-MD5", hash);
            _request.AddHeader("Authorisation", string.Format("AWS {0}:{1}", _identifier, signature));

            var response = _client.Execute(_request);

            //Check responses for any errors
            var xmlResponse = XDocument.Parse(response.Content);
            switch (response.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
                    ErrorCodeHandler(xmlResponse);
                    break;
                case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
                    ErrorCodeHandler(xmlResponse);
                    break;
                case HttpStatusCode.Accepted:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The problem lies with the response sent, which reads;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
    <Message>POST requires exactly one file upload per request.</Message>      
    <ArgumentValue>0</ArgumentValue>
    <ArgumentName>file</ArgumentName>
    <RequestId>SomeRequest</RequestId 
    <HostId>SomeID</HostId>
</Error>
```

The AWS API seems [pretty sparse](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html) on this message, and I cant quite seem to be able to figure out why the RestSharp client would be adding more than two files to the payload.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of webkitboundary. pleas try your stuff on postman - webkitboundary is very important on uploading.